# Скрыть TextView, если он пустой

Tags: android, textview

Всем привет. Как сделать чтобы TextView показывался когда там стоит какое-нибудь значение?
В макете я его скрыл, и теперь никак не могу сделать видимым при заполненном поле.

```
binding.get().phone3TextView.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            String number3 = binding.get().phone3TextView.getText().toString();

            if (!(number3.trim().isEmpty() || number3.trim().equals("-"))) {
                Utils.callPhone(ShopProfileFragment.this, number3);
            }
        });
```

```
// For phone3
        if (shop.aboutPhone3.equals("")) {
            binding.get().phone3TextView.setText(Constants.DASH);
        } else {
            binding.get().phone3TextView.setText(shop.aboutPhone3);
        }
```

макет

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/phone3TextView"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="42dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:paddingTop="4dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_body_size"
                    app:font='@{"normal"}'
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phone2TextView"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Comment: Уточните, речь об Андроиде? В любом случае необходимо хотя бы верстку посмотреть и момент назначения текстового значения для `TextView`

Comment: Да, речь об Андроид.

Comment: Так а текст Вы в каком месте для `phone3TextView` задаете?)

Comment: Текст для Phone3TextView приниммает с сервера.

Comment: У Вас есть четкая строчка в коде, где Вы этот текст назначаете для `phone3TextView`. Добавьте этот кусок кода в вопрос, пожалуйста

Comment: Добавил часть кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно сделать так:

```
if (shop.aboutPhone3.equals("")) {
    binding.get().phone3TextView.setText(Constants.DASH);
    binding.get().phone3TextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    binding.get().phone3TextView.setText(shop.aboutPhone3);
    binding.get().phone3TextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Благодарю)). Все работает.

Comment: @HARDRESET поздравляю!Не забудьте отметить ответ принятым, пожалуйста) (галочка рядом с ответом)

Comment: Готово. Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: уж лучше использовать if (!shop.aboutPhone3.isEmpty()) { // do something }